# Need to show Edit Dialog box in .net MVC5

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to show a edit dialog box. For dialog box i am using _EditModal.cshtml which accepts  `Model.WallResponses` as a model. So How can i pass @resp object when user clicks on `message-edit` button?
Bellow is my listbox.cshtml file. And i don't want to use @Html.ActionLink/@Html.Action here because it will again hit to controller which takes time.

```
@model PageableWallResponse

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach (var resp in Model.WallResponses)
{
    <div class="list-group-item" data-thread-id="@resp.ThreadId" data-message-id="@resp.Id" data-item-id="@resp">
        <span class="recipients">@resp.RecipientInfo</span>
        <abbr class="timeago badge" title="@resp.Timestamp.ToString("u")">@resp.Timestamp.ToLocalTime()</abbr>
        <div class="message">
            <span class="@(resp.Highlight ? "" : "highlight")">
                <i class="fa fa-@resp.Icon"></i> @resp.ShortDescription
            </span>

        </div>

        <div class="message-footer">
            <ul class="message-actions pull-right">
                <li>
                    <a role="button" class="message-notify" href="#" title="Remind recipient by sending a Push Notification">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i><span>Remind</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a role="button" class="message-edit" href="#" title="Edit this message">
                        <b><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></b><span>Edit</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Set a data attribute on the link that keeps the index, then use jQuery dialog to create the dialog with the partial view:

```
@model PageableWallResponse

@{
    Layout = null;
    var counter = 0;
}

@foreach (var resp in Model.WallResponses)
{
    counter++;
    <div class="list-group-item" data-thread-id="@resp.ThreadId" data-message-id="@resp.Id" data-item-id="@resp">
        <span class="recipients">@resp.RecipientInfo</span>
        <abbr class="timeago badge" title="@resp.Timestamp.ToString("u")">@resp.Timestamp.ToLocalTime()</abbr>
        <div class="message">
            <span class="@(resp.Highlight ? "" : "highlight")">
                <i class="fa fa-@resp.Icon"></i> @resp.ShortDescription
            </span>

        </div>

        <div class="message-footer">
            <ul class="message-actions pull-right">
                <li>
                    <a role="button" class="message-notify" href="#" title="Remind recipient by sending a Push Notification">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i><span>Remind</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a role="button" class="message-edit" data-index="@counter" href="#" title="Edit this message">
                        <b><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></b><span>Edit</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts{
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $(".message-edit").click(function(){
            var index = $(this).data("index");
            $("<div>").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                open: function(event, ui){
                    $(this).load("@Html.RenderPartial("_EditModal", Model.WallResponses[index])");
                },
                close: function(event, ui){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use  @Html.ActionLink, then you must use only javascript and you cannot pass @resp object (that could be used in asp mvc view generation **in the server**) .

You must write the javascript that loads selected item data and pass that data to the dialog.
If you really want to follow that way I will recommend to use some framework like [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/).

But I will recommend you to use Asp.net MVC partial views to get what you want. Of course it has to hit the controller to get the partial view, but the controller response only the view dialog so the duration of the call must be minimum.

A good response explaining partial view dialogs could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17613323/19046).