# Array is not passed to the controller from view MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my model I have these properties,

```
public string[] SelectedIDs {get; set;}
public int BookId {get;set;}
public int LanguageId {get;set;}
```

In my view I have the following,

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedIDs )
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookId )
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LanguageId )
```

Using a JavaScript array (SelectedItemIds) I am updating the SelectedIDs,

```
$a("#SelectedIDs").val(SelectedItemIds.join());
alert($a("#SelectedIDs").val());
```

The alert successfully returning comma separated values.
If I do a `post` to my action no problem, I am getting the `SelectedIDs` as comma seperated. However my requirement was to populate the view in a dialog, However while passing I am always getting `SelectedIDs` as null.

I tried with two of the following methods.

**Method 1:**

My action is:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod1(MyModel model)
{
}
```

And I used the action link as

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Book", "MyMethod1", "BookOrder", new { @id = "SubmitBooks", @class = "subBook", data_dialog_id = "AddBookDialog", data_dialog_title = "Add Books", data_dialog_width = 800, data_dialog_height = 550 })
```

In this method I successfully get `model.BookID` as well as `model.LanguageId`, but `model.SelectedIDs` was `null`.

**Method 2:**

My action is:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod2(string[] selectedItems, int bookId, int langId)
{
}
```

And I used the action link as

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Book", "MyMethod2", "BookOrder", new { @selectedItems= Model.SelectedIDs , @bookId= Model.BookId, @langId = Model.LanguageId }, new { @id = "SubmitBooks", @class = "subBook", data_dialog_id = "AddBookDialog", data_dialog_title = "Add Books", data_dialog_width = 800, data_dialog_height = 550 })
```

Here too I got both `bookid` and `langId` but no `selectedItems`, which is `null`.

Comment: In `Method 1` your model's `SelectedIDs` should be a `string` if you are using a `ActionLink` and in `Method 2`, `selectedItems` should be a `string`. Then you can use `Split` method inside your controller to create an `array` if you want one.

Comment: when you modified the hidden field, the a href parameter doesn't change since it's rendered, you should send it programmatically, register to click event, then use jquery ajax

Comment: Oh my goodness how come I missed it, In fact I tried it that too, Let me try again :)

Comment: @YuliamChandra then it will be a problem for me to get it in Dialog right?

Comment: @TBA : Did you able to get the value as a string ?

Comment: @Saranga yes I tried but no luck ...

Comment: @TBA, is it [jquery dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set traditional: true when serializing arrays.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
traditional: true,
url: "../BookOrder/MyMethod2",
data: { function_param: SelectedIDs}
```

});

Found this good explanation on what traditional: true does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497151/2419531

If you don't want to use traditional: true, you can pass the data as string using JSON.stringify and specifying the contentType:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../BookOrder/MyMethod2",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify({function_param: SelectedIDs}),
```

});

Comment: What about the Dialog Part, How can I achieve that using Ajax.

Comment: To get view in dialog use, jquery and fill values of the array when dialog loads, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613151/open-jquery-dialog-box-on-click-on-html-actionlink-mvc4

Comment: Thats why I tried to use @Html.ActionLink, but with Ajax post how could that be possible?